# How to get model for element in iron-list (polymer dart)?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I get the model for some element in `iron-list`? The documentation suggests:

```
($['list'] as IronList).modelForElement(target).index
```

but `modelForElement()` returns `TemplateInstance` which doesn't contain `index` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `get` method on the `TemplateInstance` to read any values.